# C++ std::list problems with insert

Tags: c++, stdlist

I have been at this for a few hours over the past couple of days and search as best as I could online for an answer to this and I am stuck.  Just when I think MSDN has an answer for me, I still get a problem.  I have a header `InstalledPrograms.h` with `class InstalledProgram{}`.

Three Constructors

```
#ifdef CONSTRUCTOR
    InstalledProgram::InstalledProgram();
    InstalledProgram::InstalledProgram(String^ p_DisplayName);
    InstalledProgram::InstalledProgram(String^ p_DisplayName, String^ p_ParentDisplayName, string p_Version);
#endif
```

I declare the list: `list<InstalledProgram> ProgramList;`

Pass it to this function:

```
list<InstalledProgram> InstalledProgram::GetUserUninstallKeyPrograms(RegistryKey ^CurUserInstallKey, RegistryKey^ HkeylmRoot, list<InstalledProgram> paramProgramList)
```

like this

```
GetUserUninstallKeyPrograms(Wow64UninstallKey, ClassKey, ProgramList);
```

Do some stuff and I get to a point in the code that I need to insert a new instance into the list:

`paramProgramList.insert(paramProgramList.end(), new InstalledProgram(Name));`

The Problem I have having is that the "." before insert shows "No instance of overloaded function matches the argument list", and the Parentheses around `InstalledProgram(Name)` show "No 
instance of constructor for argument type (System::String ^)".

I don't understand why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paramProgramList is a `list<InstalledProgram>` but you are trying to insert `new InstalledProgram(Name)` which is a *pointer* to an `InstalledProgram`. If `InstalledProgram` is copyable, you can just remove the word `new`.

As for "No instance of constructor for argument type (System::String ^)"; that I can't explain from the code I see unless CONSTRUCTOR is not defined.

Also, while there's nothing technically wrong with writing the insertion the way you did, this would be a bit more succinct:

```
paramProgramList.push_back(InstalledProgram(Name));
```

Comment: I didn't have a copy constructor.  I didn't think I would use one. But I added one and it still refused to accept the parameter Name which is String^.  I ended up having to create a empty new instance, set the value manually and then do a copy before passing it to push_back.

Comment: I can't say for sure without seeing the whole definition of InstalledProgram, but if that's true, I think it must mean that CONSTRUCTOR isn't defined.